# current_user returns nil even when user_signed_in? returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have devise 2.1.2 and cancan 1.6.8 installed.

The `current_user` helper from devise works fine in my controllers, but is not working the view templates. I'm confused why this is happening. I've been able to use `current_user` in my view files before.

I tried adding the before_filter `authenticate_user!` and that didn't help.

Worse comes to worse, I'll add a before filter to the application_controller that says `@current_user = current_user` but that seems silly.

It's weird that `current_user` returns nil while `user_signed_in?` returns true.

Any thoughts on how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the meantime,`warden.authenticate(:scope => :user)` seems to return the `current_user` so I'm just going to add that to my application helper.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, and am not finding a solution. Your workaround above works, but I was wondering if you ever found a solution to the problem.

Comment: I did. I had accidentally made a helper method called `current_user` that must have been overloading the devise helper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was actually my problem too. I was upgrading from rails 2 and was using restful_authentication, which had a user helper that was interfering.